# Find the smallest number Q whose product of digits is N

Tags: c

How do I make this efficient?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000000000

int main()
{
    int n,temp,prod,i,j=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=1;i<MAX;i++)
    {
        temp=i;
        prod=1;
        while(temp!=0)
        {
           prod=prod*(temp%10);
           temp=temp/10;
        }
        if(prod==n)
        {
            printf("%d",i);
            j=1;
            break;
        }

    }
    if(j==0)
    {
        printf("-1");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are going about this problem the wrong way. Think about math.

Comment: The only problem with going up to 10e9 is if your compiler defines `int` as 32-bit. If you can use a 64-bit integer, you're good to go. If not, you'll need to find a library that implements an arbitrary-precision integer.

Answer (score 5):

> An efficient solution would be to express n as its prime
>   factorization \$2^a3^b5^c7^d\$. Then, try to regroup those factors into the
>   fewest number of 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 digits possible, in increasing
>   order. If n has a prime factor larger than 7, then there is no
>   solution.

The right way to group the \$2^a3^b\$ factors in 2,3,6,8,9 digits is first to minimize the number of digits, giving priority to \$2^3\$. You then end up with \$3^b\$ or \$2^13^b\$ or \$2^23^b\$. For \$b>2\$ you group by \$3^2\$. I then solved all the solutions for \$2^a3^b\$ with \$a,b\leq2\$ and figured out that the following precedence works : (9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2). So there must be a more elegant proof!

Note that the solution will have at most one 2 or one 3 or one 4.

```
int numberOfFactor(int * n, int factor)
{
    int number_of_factor = 0;
    while (*n % factor == 0)
    {
        *n /= factor;
        number_of_factor++;
    }
    return number_of_factor;
}

int appendDigits(int digit, int n_digit, int initial_shift)
{
    int i;
    int ret = 0;

    for (i=0; i<n_digit; i++)
        ret = ret + digit * pow (10, i + initial_shift);

    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int q;
    int n9, n8, n7, n6, n5;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n <= 9)
    {
        printf("%d", n);
        return 0;
    }

    n9 = numberOfFactor(&n, 9);
    n8 = numberOfFactor(&n, 8);
    n7 = numberOfFactor(&n, 7);
    n6 = numberOfFactor(&n, 6);
    n5 = numberOfFactor(&n, 5);


    if (n>4)
    {
        printf("-1");
        return 1;
    }

    q = appendDigits(9,n9,0) 
      + appendDigits(8,n8,n9)
      + appendDigits(7,n7,n9+n8)
      + appendDigits(6,n6,n9+n8+n7)
      + appendDigits(5,n5,n9+n8+n7+n6)
      + ((n!=1)?appendDigits(n,1,n9+n8+n7+n6+n5):0);

    printf("%d", q);
    return 0;
}
```

My first post, please be indulgent.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, Hugo Elbzh. I think it's awesome that your first post is an answer. I hope you enjoy the site.

Comment: For N=18, the answer should be Q=29. Your code prints 36 instead.

Comment: I fixed it. You can now merge the 2 functions I declared to build the solution while factorizing. And you can loop from 9 down to 5 to have a very concise code.

Comment: I suggest just printing the digits directly instead of trying to create an int.  Either that or create a string.  For example, your program doesn't handle N=9765625 because that is 5^10, and you can't fit 5555555555 in an int.

Comment: It's true I did not check for overflow. But the question is "find the number" not "print the number", so I interpret the answer should be an int

Answer (score 4):

Your program is not written clearly.  Some code smells include:

- An abundance of variables (`temp`, `prod`, `i`, `j`).
- Any variable named `temp` could always have a better name.
- Terminology is inconsistent (you used "Q" in the question, but the variable is called `temp`).
- Any flag variable (`j` in this case) is a likely indicator of ineffective flow control.
- The purposes of the loops are not as obvious as they could be.
- The `MAX` constant seems arbitrary.  (On a system with 16-bit `int`, this code would break.)

It should look like this:

```
int productOfDigits(int q)
{
    int product = 1;
    while (q)
    {
        product *= q % 10;
        q /= 10;
    }
    return product;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int q = 1; q > 0; q++)
    {
        if (productOfDigits(q) == n)
        {
            printf("%d", q);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("-1");
    return 1;
}
```

But that's a very brute-force approach.  An efficient solution would be to express *n* as its prime factorization 2<sup>*a*</sup>3<sup>*b*</sup>5<sup>*c*</sup>7<sup>*d*</sup>.  Then, try to regroup those factors into the fewest number of 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 digits possible, in increasing order.  If *n* has a prime factor larger than 7, then there is no solution. (Why?)

Comment: ths does not up the efficiency of the program very much. i mean the algorithm is much the same.

Comment: As I said, this code is just a clearer implementation of your brute-force approach. I've outlined a strategy for an efficient solution, but I decline to implement it for you.

Comment: btw why did you return 1 in the last line? why not return 0? any difference?

Comment: Exiting with a non-zero status is a common convention to indicate failure.